# Elements not adding to UIStackView , programmatically?

Tags: swift, uikit, xcode11, uistackview, ios14

I was trying to make a sorting Visualizer in Live playground so I created a stack view but when I try to add UIView (as the sticks in that visualiser) they do not get added in my stackView , **Below is my code
It is big but your are interested in mainStackview part only because that is the stackView where I wanna add that sticks(UIView), Also buildStartingArray() function (it is used to add the UIViews)**

```
public class HomeViewController:UIViewController{

    let stackView:UIStackView = {
       let st = UIStackView()
        st.axis = .horizontal
        st.alignment = .center
        st.distribution = .fill
//        st.backgroundColor = .cyan
        st.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        st.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        st.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        st.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        st.spacing = 10
        st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
       return st
    }()
    let generateButton:UIButton = {
       let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Generate Array", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.92, green: 0.30, blue: 0.29, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let BubbleSort:UIButton = {
       let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("BubbleSort", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.41, green: 0.43, blue: 0.88, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let MergeSort:UIButton = {
       let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("MergeSort", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.10, green: 0.16, blue: 0.34, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let InsertionSort:UIButton = {
       let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("InsertionSort", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.19, green: 0.22, blue: 0.32, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let SelectionSort:UIButton = {
       let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("SelectionSort", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.51, green: 0.20, blue: 0.44, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let mainStackView:UIStackView = {
        let st = UIStackView()
        st.backgroundColor = .gray
        st.axis = .horizontal
        st.distribution = .fillEqually
        st.alignment = .firstBaseline
        st.spacing = 1
        st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return st
    }()
    let baseView:UIView = {
        let vw = UIView()
        vw.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.07, green: 0.54, blue: 0.65, alpha: 1.00)
        vw.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vw.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        vw.layer.masksToBounds = true
        vw.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
        return vw
    }()
    public override   func viewDidLoad() {
          view.addSubview(mainStackView)
          view.addSubview(stackView)
          view.addSubview(baseView)
        edgesForExtendedLayout = []
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(generateButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(BubbleSort)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(MergeSort)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(InsertionSort)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(SelectionSort)
        
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        
        baseView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor,constant: -2).isActive = true
        baseView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor,constant: 5).isActive = true
        baseView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor,constant: -5).isActive = true

         mainStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        mainStackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        mainStackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        mainStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: baseView.topAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        setButtons()
        builStartingArray()

    }

   func setButtons(){
        generateButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(generatePressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        BubbleSort.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bubbleSort), for: .touchUpInside)
        MergeSort.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mergeSort), for: .touchUpInside)
        InsertionSort.addTarget(self, action: #selector(insertionSort), for: .touchUpInside)
        SelectionSort.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectionSort), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    func builStartingArray(){
        let viewStick:UIView = {
           let v = UIView()
            v.backgroundColor = .red
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            v.frame.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 150)
            return v
        }()
        let viewStick2:UIView = {
           let v = UIView()
            v.backgroundColor = .red
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            v.frame.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 150)
            return v
        }()
        mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(viewStick)
        mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(viewStick2)
    }
}
```

Problem is the UIView that I add in buildStartingArray() function doesn't show up ,And
for now I have added only 2 view but in future I am planning to add 30-35 in mainStackView,

I want those UIViews to look like graph bars and the mainStackView is my graph

Here is the current output
[image: Output]
the mainStackView is the one with gray background

Comment: try to remove `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and let stackview sets its content.

Comment: add a reproducible code or a github link

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz , of what the view or mainStack , which ones to remove??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make main stackView to align bottom

You can try to adding a height for mainStack subviews like

```
v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
```

in

```
func builStartingArray(){
    let viewStick:UIView = {
       let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        return v
    }()
    let viewStick2:UIView = {
       let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        return v
    }()
    mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(viewStick)
    mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(viewStick2)
}
```

All code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController:UIViewController{

   let stackView:UIStackView = {
       let st = UIStackView()
        st.axis = .horizontal
        st.alignment = .center
        st.distribution = .fill
//        st.backgroundColor = .cyan
        st.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        st.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        st.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        st.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        st.spacing = 10
        st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
       return st
    }()
    let generateButton:UIButton = {
       let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Generate Array", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.92, green: 0.30, blue: 0.29, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let BubbleSort:UIButton = {
       let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("BubbleSort", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.41, green: 0.43, blue: 0.88, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let MergeSort:UIButton = {
       let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("MergeSort", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.10, green: 0.16, blue: 0.34, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let InsertionSort:UIButton = {
       let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("InsertionSort", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.19, green: 0.22, blue: 0.32, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let SelectionSort:UIButton = {
       let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("SelectionSort", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.51, green: 0.20, blue: 0.44, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let mainStackView:UIStackView = {
        let st = UIStackView()
        st.backgroundColor = .gray
        st.axis = .horizontal
        st.distribution = .fillEqually
        st.alignment = .top
        st.spacing = 1
        st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return st
    }()
    let baseView:UIView = {
        let vw = UIView()
        vw.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.07, green: 0.54, blue: 0.65, alpha: 1.00)
        vw.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vw.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        vw.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return vw
    }()
    public override   func viewDidLoad() {
          view.addSubview(mainStackView)
          view.addSubview(stackView)
          view.addSubview(baseView)
        edgesForExtendedLayout = []
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(generateButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(BubbleSort)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(MergeSort)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(InsertionSort)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(SelectionSort)
        
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        
        baseView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor,constant: -2).isActive = true
        baseView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor,constant: 5).isActive = true
        baseView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor,constant: -5).isActive = true
        baseView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
        
        mainStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        mainStackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        mainStackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        mainStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: baseView.topAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
 
        builStartingArray()

    }
 
    func builStartingArray(){
        let viewStick:UIView = {
           let v = UIView()
            v.backgroundColor = .red
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
            return v
        }()
        let viewStick2:UIView = {
           let v = UIView()
            v.backgroundColor = .red
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
            return v
        }()
        mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(viewStick)
        mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(viewStick2)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: set height for `baseView` you have an ambiguous height ? what you get now ?

Comment: base view has heightAnchor set , And what does it has to base view ? , the problem is with mainStackView

Comment: it does relate as the remaining height will be set for main/stack , i do't see `heightAnchor` for `baseView` i your code

Comment: ooh I apologise for that , I edited it now please check , thank you , the code for baseView is right above the viewdidload

Comment: hey @Sh_Khan , its working but if I set height of one view greater than other than the view with smaller height has gap below and they endup being the same height ??
I want it to look like graph see like this https://camo.githubusercontent.com/08f0397b53b47308f35100650285950aca575a8b2cfcb48ab6c1dcfa9c753047/68747470733a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f5a34304e52354a2e706e67 
  , I dont want that many bars though but at least 30-40

Comment: when you set different heights you will get different looks and no they won't be same height you can play with stack alignment

Comment: hey @Sh_Khan , alignment = bottom worked thank you .

Comment: hey @Sh_Khan , i was just curious , so I just Made the mainStackView public and in the main file tried to print mainStackView.frame.size.height than the output is zero , How is this possible ? I can see that giant stackView infront of me how can the height be printed zero than ??

Comment: this depends on time of doing that , the vc must be fully presented to have a value

Comment: hey @Sh_Khan ,now I did that in viewdidload() the code is  the same I just added this line viewDidLoad. `print("this is stackView height:\(mainStackView.frame.size.height)")`
and its still showing 0.0
I never set any explicit height for mainStackView though only had set the top , bottom , left , right anchor , so is that the culprit for the problem?

Comment: add another question to clarify what you have add its link here for specific help